# How can ParametricPlot3D assign different colors to two curves from a function that returns 2 triples? Yes, I have tried "Evaluate"

Tags: plotting, color

I have a funciton of the sort

```
myFn[t_]:=Module[{...},
 (* some computation *)
 { {x1,y1,z1}, {x2, y2, z2} }];
```

When I call it as:

```
ParametricPlot3D[ myFn[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi } , PlotStyle->{Red,Green} ]
```

I can't for the life of me, make the two colors appear. Both curves will be colored the same way. Yes, I have put Evaluate@myFn[t] yadayadayada.

I am running Mathematica Home Edition v10. This problem has persisted for years! (a decade?)

Comment: I see no problem with `Evaluate@myFn[t]` (without yadayadayada though). `myFn[t_] := Module[{},
  {{0, t, 0}, {1, t, 0}}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@myFn[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]` returns one blue line, one red line.

Comment: What is your `MyFn`?